# How can I have months update automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have a list of the months like this

```
<div id="dailyInfo" class="contentInfo">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#February">Febuary</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#March">March</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#April">April</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#May">May</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#June">June</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#July">July</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#August">August</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#September">September</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#October">October</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#November">November</a>
                    </li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Is there way to hide the October until it is October? The same with November. Right now I'm commenting these out and switching it every month. The only problem is I'll sometimes be late a few days. How could I make this happen automatically?

Edit: I'd like to have all `li` elements of past months showing. Just not the months that haven't come yet. Like October and November

Comment: Do you mean hide all `li` elements but the current month? If so use something like `var date = new Date(); var month = date.getMonth(); document.getElementById(month).style.diplay = "inline";` assuming you hide them using `display:none;`

Answer (score 3):

Hide every month after the current one :

```
$('#dailyInfo li:gt('+((new Date()).getMonth()-1)+')').hide();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yLqgf/)

Hide everything but the current month :

```
$('#dailyInfo li:not(li:eq('+((new Date()).getMonth()-1)+'))').hide();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yLqgf/1/)

Hide the current month :

```
$('#dailyInfo li:eq('+((new Date()).getMonth()-1)+')').hide();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yLqgf/2/)

Answer (score 1):

adeneo has posted a great answer, but I thought I could provide another one. Just for Pete's sake.

http://jsfiddle.net/G6wWa/

```
var d = new Date(),
    n = d.getMonth();

$(".contentInfo ul li").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        ID = $(this).index();
    if (ID > n) $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code...it will hide your current month

here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K7Thm/

```
 var currentDate=new Date()
    var monthNum=currentDate.getMonth()-1;
    $('#dailyInfo ul li').eq(monthNum).hide();
```